# How to delete a moderated site in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

A moderated site was created by an user long back. This is before I restricted the creation of site only for a particular group. I need to delete the site. Strangely admin login cant join this site or delete this site without being added by the user. Any idea on how to delete this site?

Comment: Which version are you on? In the 4.x version as admin there is an option "become site manager".

Comment: No there is only join site option is there and if I click it is saying `Your request has been sent for approval. You will taken to your dashboard`

Comment: @TahirMalik I managed to do by editing the property of the particular site from `MODERATED` to `PUBLIC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login as admin

- go to the group administration
- check box to the upper right to show system groups
- click browse
- add admin user to the site-manager group of the site you want to delete

Now admin is a member and should be able to delete it.